# How would I query so that I display every users most recent location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How would I write a query to show the latest location for each user similar to how I have show? I've searched around but keep failing to implement it correctly.

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Username | Firstname | Lastname | Location  |       DateandTime       |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| ms       | mark      | smith    | labs      | 2017-05-04 15:35:00.000 |
| jb       | james     | brown    | home      | 2017-05-04 18:55:00.000 |
| cj       | charlie   | jones    | uni       | 2017-05-04 18:56:00.000 |
| cj       | charlie   | jones    | home      | 2017-05-04 19:33:00.000 |
| ms       | mark      | smith    | shop      | 2017-05-05 15:40:00.000 |
| jb       | james     | brown    | somewhere | 2017-05-05 16:31:00.000 |
| ms       | mark      | smith    | work      | 2017-05-07 17:42:00.000 |
| ms       | mark      | smith    | market    | 2017-05-07 17:45:00.000 |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+

+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Username | Firstname | Lastname | Location  |       DateandTime       |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| cj       | charlie   | jones    | home      | 2017-05-04 19:33:00.000 |
| jb       | james     | brown    | somewhere | 2017-05-05 16:31:00.000 |
| ms       | mark      | smith    | market    | 2017-05-07 17:45:00.000 |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function `row_number` with `top 1 with ties` to get the latest one row for each username.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from your_table
order by row_number() over (
        partition by username order by dateandtime desc
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
;with cte_a as
(
    select distinct username, Firstname, Lastname from dbo.mytable
)
select a.username, a.Firstname, a.Lastname, q.[Location] [Last Location], q.DateAndTime
from cte_a a
outer apply
(
    select top 1 b.[Location], b.DateAndTime
    from dbo.myTable b 
    where b.Username = a.username
    order by DateAndTime desc
)q
```

Comment: Other answer by @Gurwinder Singh is nicer than mine. :)

Comment: I don't know I think apply is more efficient.